# How to concatenate labels in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I'm using QGIS 1.8 on windows XP machine and I try to do a concatenation of several fields to label the names of my local roads in the attribute table, but I can not find the correct syntax. The first field consists of om the street, the second type of link, eg: Avenue and the third orientation, for example, East or West. Could you tell me how to write the correct syntax using the dialog box of labels based on a formula.
  Attached a screenshot that shows the attribute table.

[image]

Answer (score 24):

The concatenation operator is `||` (odd huh?), so you would use something like:

```
street || ', ' || link || ', ' || orientation
```

Intersperse them with any separators and static strings you like.

As @NathanW noted, this will fail if any of the fields is NULL, but you can use a fallback value in that case:

```
street || ', ' || CASE WHEN ("link" IS NULL) THEN '(nodata)' ELSE "link" END || ', ' || orientation
```

QGIS supports a helper function `coalesce` since version 2.0. It is there to avoid the problems of NULLs and the example would look like:

```
 street || ', ' || coalesce(link, '(nodata)') || ', ' || orientation
```

Comment: There is also the `concat` function in the dev versions.  Using || doesn't handle NULL, if `link` is NULL the whole label is null `concat` doesn't have this issue.  || is taken from Postgres http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html

Comment: Looks like it doesn't support case statements directly. Is the only option without using SQL directly to create a non-NULL copy of the link column?

Comment: What do you mean doesn't support case statements?

Comment: I tried just: CASE WHEN ("link" IS NULL) THEN '(nodata)' ELSE "link" -- but it was a syntax error

Comment: You are missing END.  The correct string is `CASE WHEN ("link" IS NULL) THEN '(nodata)' ELSE "link" END`

Comment: doh, silly me. :) Too bad it doesn't support ternary though.

Comment: `concat` in master also has that "issue".   but master also has `coalesce(link,'(nodata)')` (shorter than CASE).

Comment: ahh `coalesce` is the the one I meant.

Answer (score 3):

On QGIS veriosn 2.0.1 the simple expression worked like this:

"field1"  || ' (' || "field2"  || ')'

desired output: field1 (field2)